# Using fprinf function in Matlab to change the voltage and current of power supply to make GUI

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make the voltage and current as the input variable to change the voltage and current in the power source. I want it to make this into GUI so that the user and type in the voltage and current which will change the values in the power supply. As a trial I used:

```
voltage = 1;
current = 1;
fprintf('APPL %d , %d', voltage, current);
```

which worked as it printed

```
APPL 1 , 1
```

The original code for changing the power source is:

```
    %% HighV Voltage Power Supply
%Instrument Connection

% Find a serial port object.
% Find a tcpip object.
obj1 = instrfind('Type', 'tcpip', 'RemoteHost', '192.168.0.111', 'RemotePort', 2268, 'Tag', '');

% Create the tcpip object if it does not exist
% otherwise use the object that was found.
if isempty(obj1)
    obj1 = tcpip('192.168.0.111', 2268);
else
    fclose(obj1);
    obj1 = obj1(1);
end

%% Disconnect and Clean Up

% Disconnect from instrument object, obj1.
fclose(obj1);

%% Instrument Connection

% Connect to instrument object, obj1.
fopen(obj1);

%% Instrument Configuration and Control
% Communicating with instrument object, obj1.
fprintf(obj1, 'APPL 2,1.5'); %setting voltage and current syntax: 'APPL voltage,current'

fprintf(obj1, 'DISPlay:MENU:NAME 3'); %To display changed voltage and current on the screen panel on the high voltage supply
```

This code worked as the voltage and the current changed to 2v and 1.5A on the power supply.
However using the test from earlier I change the code to:

```
%% HighV Voltage Power Supply
%Instrument Connection

% Find a serial port object.
% Find a tcpip object.
obj1 = instrfind('Type', 'tcpip', 'RemoteHost', '192.168.0.111', 'RemotePort', 2268, 'Tag', '');

% Create the tcpip object if it does not exist
% otherwise use the object that was found.
if isempty(obj1)
    obj1 = tcpip('192.168.0.111', 2268);
else
    fclose(obj1);
    obj1 = obj1(1);
end

%% Disconnect and Clean Up

% Disconnect from instrument object, obj1.
fclose(obj1);

%% Instrument Connection

% Connect to instrument object, obj1.
fopen(obj1);

%% Instrument Configuration and Control
% Communicating with instrument object, obj1.

voltage = 1;
current = 1;
fprintf(obj1, 'APPL %d , %d', voltage, current);

fprintf(obj1, 'DISPlay:MENU:NAME 3'); %To display changed voltage and current on the screen panel on the high voltage supply
```

This code gives an error message of:

```
Error using icinterface/fprintf (line 124)
MODE must be either 'sync' or 'async'.

Error in HighVoltageSupply (line 32)
fprintf(obj1, 'APPL %d , %d', voltage, current);
```

How can I fix this? I want to be able to put voltage and current as input.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that Matlab uses the same function `fprintf` for two different purposes.
The one in your first example `fprintf('APPL %d , %d', voltage, current);` is to write a string to a file (or in this case to the screen).
The second one `fprintf(obj1, 'APPL 2,1.5');` is to send a command to an instrument.

In your error, you're basically trying to do a mix of the two, which is not allowed.
What you can do is then first to create a string with, for example, `sprintf`, and then pass this string as command.

```
s = sprintf('APPL %d , %d', voltage, current);
fprintf(obj1, s);
```

or, in a single line

```
fprintf(obj1, sprintf('APPL %d , %d', voltage, current));
```